# My bootstrap nav menu doesn't collapse when a li choice is made

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar, nav

I'm trying to start my own business and looking to save a bit of money by using a bootstrap 3 based template I purchased.

The menu on mobiles doesn't collapse when a menu item is chosen nor when someone clicks outside the menu. Apparently it's not supposed to which strikes me as wildly counterintuitive but there we go. How might I go about getting it to collapse when a subject is chosen OR someone clicks outside the menu, please? There are similar questions here but none of them have worked for me thus far. I'm probably doing something stupid though.

```
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-header col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-res"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span> </button>
                            <!--======= LOGO =========-->
                            <div class="logo col-2"><img src="images/pdriving4.png" alt="" ></div>
                        </div>

                        <!--======= MENU =========-->
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-res">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="dropdown active"> <a href="index.php" class="dropdown-toggle">Home </a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#inspectors" class="dropdown-toggle">About Paul</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#portfolio" class="dropdown-toggle">Passed Gallery </a>   </li> 
                                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#pricing" class="dropdown-toggle">Courses </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#interested">Contact</a></li>                                                            
                                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#news" class="dropdown-toggle">FAQs </a></li>                                        
                                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="Payment_page_now.php" class="dropdown-toggle">Book Now </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Comment: Did you add bootstrap js files in your project ?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed.

Comment: Can you reproduce issue in a js fiddle ? Your partial html is not enough